# SWIFT 2.0: map & join

Tags: swift, join, dictionary

After switching to XCode 7 b5 I get an error on

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : CustomStringConvertible>(elements: S) -> String {
        return self.join(map(elements){ $0.description })
    }
}
```

return statement is wrong!

> "map is unavailable: Call the map() method on the sequence..."

I could not find the correct new syntax in combination on map and join. Any idea?

Comment: `map(elements)` becomes `elements.map`

Answer (score 2):

What jtbandes said. Like this:

```
extension String {
    func join<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element : CustomStringConvertible>(elements: S) -> String {
        return self.join(elements.map({ $0.description }))
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. Only map syntax has changed! Thank you very much. It works.